# How to change the size of UIStackView on storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistackview

I use `UIStackView` on storyboard and put two `UIButton` on the stack view. However, once the buttons are added to the stack view, it seems that I cannot alter the frame of the stack view.

For your information, I can move the stack view on the canvas; I just cannot change the size of the stack view.

Also, the text field is grayed out on the Inspector. How can I change the size of it?

[image]